# Why in 2-hydroxybutanenitrile is there no syntax saying where in the compound the nitrile is?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was asked to name the compound in question, and it seems as though the nitrile could be at either end from the name alone.

What removes the ambiguity? Could the nitrile not be either 1 or 4, since there’s an even number of carbons in the chain?

Comment: The nitrile can only be at the end of the chain, and you start the numbering from that end because it takes priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](https://doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*,

> **P-14.4 Numbering**
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
> [...]
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);

Because the nitrile is considered the principal characteristic group, the triply bonded carbon is given the lowest possible locant number '1'.

[image: Numbering in 2-hydroxybutanenitrile]

> **P-14.3.4 Omission of locants** [...] Locants are omitted in preferred IUPAC names in the following cases:
>
> **P-14.3.4.1** Terminal locants are not cited in names for mono- and dicarboxylic acids derived from acyclic hydrocarbons and their corresponding acyl halides, amides, hydrazides, nitriles, aldehydes, amidines, amidrazones, hydrazidines, and amidoximes, when unsubstituted or substituted on carbon atoms.

The terminal locant '1' for the suffix nitrile is therefore omitted in the preferred IUPAC name (PIN).

As long as you are following the IUPAC guidelines for the generation of a PIN, there is no ambiguity, because the nitrile must be given the locant '1'. It is just not written explicitly in the PIN.